# How to declare a variable of struct that declared inside another struct?

Tags: c

I have a struct that declared as follow:

```c
struct a {
    struct b {
        int d;
    } c;
};
```

How to declare a variable of `b` outside `a`? In C++ I can use `a::b x;`. But, in C it required to specifies `struct` keyword before struct name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C has a flat layout; when you declare a struct within another struct, the former is just being put into the global namespace.

So, in your example, it is just `struct b`.

Comment: Where does the standard say that?

Comment: @david.pfx not sure, but 6.2.1 `If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears outside of any block or list of parameters, the identifier has file scope`

Comment: @keltar: Actually, no. I think it might be 6.2.3 Name spaces and note 32, which make it clear there is only one namespace for tags, but a separate namespace for members of each struct or union.

Answer (score 1):

C does not have nested types. You can't write `a::x b` or anything that ressembles it. If you want to get rid of the `struct` keyword, that's another problem. Use `typedef`s. but it won't allow to nest types.

```
typedef struct b_t {
  int d;
} b;
typedef struct {
  b c;
} a;
b some_b;
a some_a;
int f() {
  some_b.d=42;
  some_a.c=some_b;
  return 0;
```

}

.